# 16.04 - 32 bit Ubuntu online upgrade to 18.04 Failure

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, upgrade, update-manager

I had gotten the message on my software updater that there was an update from 16.04 to 18.04 and it appeared valid.  I had been putting it off as I usually wait before moving to the latest LTS release.  Long story short I finally chose to update and now I'm stuck.  It appears to be booting up but then goes to a blank screen and nothing seems to work.  I try to get to a console by pressing Cntr + Alt + f1 and I get no prompt to login.  went through all of the console sessions not one of them work.  When I press the power button it appears to be shutting down I see the the Ubuntu splash screen and the laptop powers off.  When I boot up I see the same splash screen and then it just goes to a blank screen??  Anyone have any thoughts??  Dam why would they allow an upgrade to process if the processor type is a miss-match?

Any help or direction on how to recover back to 16.04 would be helpful.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it). It's not about what "they" didn't "allow."

Comment: There's no 32-bit version in 18.04. you should keep 16.04, supported until 2021. Before its support expires you need to study and consider alternatives if you want to keep using that old computer.

Comment: Just did google search and found this.  https://itsfoss.com/ubuntu-18-04-faq/  does not help much, but might lead to other answers, down to third answer.

Comment: If you used power-off; I'd firstly boot a live (install-media) system and `fsck` your disk, and suggest you use magic sysrq keys to shutdown the machine if possible in future. I would edit your grub entry to remove `quiet splash` so you can see more messages instead of just your plymouth screen. I'd look for clues as to problem, but then likely add a '1' too to force runlevel 1 and explore (see prior duplicate link for example).  Flavors have x86 install ISO's so I would use one of them to re-install 18.04 (something-else & no-format; there is a 18.04 x86 non-desktop install too)

Comment: If you have important, non back up data on 16.04, would stop using it and look for data recovery answers.  Other wise a clean install of a 32 bit OS might be easiest.

Comment: Lubuntu has a 32 bit  release of 18.04 LTS.